# How to bind gridview using linq/Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I need to bind `GridView`, I am using this code:

```
  ProductDBEntities db = new ProductPDBEntities();

    var pro = from u in db.Products where u.PID == 1 select u;

    if (pro != null)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = pro;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

and getting this error.

> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Sequence contains more than one
>   element

Can somebody please tell me what am I doin wrong?

Comment: I think you will need to convert it to **ToList()** for it to work as DataSource for a gridview

Comment: i tried ToList function its give me this error .. Data source is an invalid type.  It must be either an IListSource, IEnumerable, or IDataSource

ELAPDBEntities db = new ELAPDBEntities();

            var assetFinan = from u in db.AssetFinancings where u.AppID == AppID select u;

            if (assetFinan != null)
            {

                gvAssetFinance.DataSource = assetFinan.ToList();
                gvAssetFinance.DataBind();

            }

Comment: U need to get ToList when you are assigning it to **pro**

Comment: can you give me an example .. please

Comment: You don't need `ToList()`. You can bind an `IEnumerable` to a GridView. And `pro` in your code is an `IQueryable` which *is* an `IEnumerable`. The exception makes no sense in the context of the code you have shown above. On which line do you get exactly this exception when you debug?

Comment: @Kay: Can you show more of your code (the GridView part in your aspx file, perhaps other event handlers of the GridView you have implemented, etc.)? The origin of this exception must be somewhere else, the code you have shown is valid. (For instance: the `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()` extension methods are a candidate for this exception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `Duplication` and then try to bind it.

I have edited my last answer in order to display the complete code :

```
ProductDBEntities db = new ProductPDBEntities();
GridView1.DataSource = (from u in db.Products where u.PID == 1 select u).First();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: thanks for that .. but i m having problem displaying. getting error .. can you post your code how do you bind the gridview ?

Comment: `First()` returns a `Product` object. I don't think that this object has a `ToList()` method, has it?

Answer (score 1):

This code may be helpful:

```
    gv.DataSource = (from u in db.Products .First(u=> u.PID==1)).ToList();
```

If you have a table and table detail can use this one:

```
    gv.DataSource = (from a in context.tblorder.First(p => p.id == 19).tblorderdetail where a.ID == 19 select a).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you might check your data to see if there's more than one product with PID = 1.

Second, you can use the .First() method to make sure you get only one result for binding:

```
var pro = (from u in db.Products where u.PID == 1 select u).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do `ToList()` when to add to `DataSource`:

```
ProductDBEntities db = new ProductPDBEntities();

var pro = from u in db.Products where u.PID == 1 select u;

if (pro != null)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = pro.ToList();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Note: As it is a `GridView`, has to take n number of rows. `No row limit`.

Answer (score 0):

Store the variable to object type and assign the object type as datasource to grid

Answer (score 0):

### I solve like this:

```
ProductDBEntities ctx = new ProductDBEntities ();
var q1 = ctx.Products.Where(x => x.PID == 1).ToList();
GridView1.DataSource = q1;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

*I try it. It's work.*