# RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render

Tags: asp.net, jquery, rendercontrol

I have a webmethod which will be called from jquery ajax:

```
[WebMethod]
public string TestMethod(string param1, string param2)
{
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(b));
    this.LoadControl("~/Pages/Controls/Listing.ascx").RenderControl(h);
    string controlAsString = b.ToString();
    return controlAsString;
}
```

(it's a non-static method and we are able to hit it. That's not an issue)

When the loadControl() method is executed, I get an error saying: RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render.

I have already included EnableEventValidation="false" for the current aspx, disabled viewstate also. but still i get the same error. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 63):

Solution is to disable the Page's Event Validation as 
 `<%@ Page ............  EnableEventValidation="false" %>`

and Override VerifyRenderingInServerForm by adding following method in your C# code behind

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}
```

Refer the Below Link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/45450/RegisterForEventValidation-can-only-be-called-duri

Comment: Thank you!  This was exactly the answer I needed for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24457003/363892.

Comment: could you help on this for same.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629644/how-to-export-excel-without-enableeventvalidation-false-because-of-lock-issues

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the error: VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control): no suitable method found to override

Comment: You current class where your writting this should be proper class inheritted from Page base class
@JancodeVries : Try as stated in "Solution 1" of this https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/321382/about-VerifyRenderingInServerForm-event

Comment: You'll see this when someone uses async void in page events despite that not really being supported. Resolve by using one of the many AsyncUtils to run any async code in a sync handler or use the RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask()) method supported by ASP.NET webforms.

Answer (score 12):

As per Brian's second link, without hopping further, just do this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
Html32TextWriter hw = new Html32TextWriter(sw);

Page page = new Page();
HtmlForm f = new HtmlForm();
page.Controls.Add(f);
f.Controls.Add(ctrl);
// ctrl.RenderControl(hw); 
// above line will raise "RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();"
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, true);
Response.Write(sb);
```

Comment: could you help on this for same.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40629644/how-to-export-excel-without-enableeventvalidation-false-because-of-lock-issues

Comment: You saved my day !

Comment: @SukhvindraSingh sorry for late reply. just go check my answer on that question. thanks.

Comment: Can anyone explain this one to those of us finding this now? Declaration of **ctrl** is missing, for starters. (It mentions an unknown Brian, so maybe it refers to a now-deleted answer or comment that explained what this is doing...?)

Comment: @MGOwen the "ctrl" is short of "control"  and it is a var that you declare anywhere to hold a ref to Control object.Since we are talking about adding control in the page controls so declare the control anywhere in the code before f.Control.Add(ctrl) and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify ASP.Net that not to validate the event by setting the `EnableEventValidation` flag to `false`.

You can set it in the Web.Config in the following way

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation = "false"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).