# How can I copy HTML ASP.NET VB Form/Table to send as email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, email, html-email

I have a few large, specifically formatted to the customer's request, tables with input. It looks similar to the following...

```
<body id="Body" class="Window" runat="server">
    <form id="Form" runat="server" defaultbutton="SubmitLinkButton">
        <!-- Markup for a the SubmitLinkButton and DropDownList -->
        <!--    to pick which Table is shown                    -->
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow class="row" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <pre>    Some Input1    </pre>
                    <pre>___________________</pre>
                    <pre>|___<asp:Textbox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>____|</pre>
                    <pre>|_________________|</pre>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow class="row" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <pre>    Some Input2    </pre>
                    <pre>___________________</pre>
                    <pre>|___<asp:Textbox ID="Textbox2" runat="server"></asp:Textbox>____|</pre>
                    <pre>|_________________|</pre>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Underwhelming, right?

Only one of the four tables is visible or not depending on the selection chosen in the DropDownList. Each table has upwards of 30-40 inputs and each area with inputs is formatted uniquely. All formatted the same way (^^^like above^^^), but one may have a section with 3 inputs and lots of text or 8 inputs and little text or no inputs and just a section of text.

Hopefully all of that makes sense.

What I need to figure out is how to have the user be able to "Submit" the form via the `SubmitLinkButton` which will send an email that looks identical to the form they filled out to a group of email addresses setup in the `SystemFramwork.config`.

I've attempted to do this, using `Visual Basic`, with `RenderControl()`, but I kept getting errors saying my Textboxes needed to be inside a form with `runat="server"` in it, and as you can see in my code above I have that. So, I'm not sure what was going on there.

Since the form is formatted so customized, If I can't somehow render the HTML form from page to email to have them look identical, I don't know any other option than to add the markup to the email manually, which just seems like a waste of time and making redundancies in the project.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

I'm still currently working with a pseudo solution that looks something like this...

```
Public Sub SubmitLinkButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitLinkButton.Click
    Dim result As String = vbNull

    Dim stringWriter As New StringWriter()
    Dim htmlWriter As New HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter)

    'If the user selected something with the DropDown
    If (DDL_Selection IsNot "")
        Dim email As New MailMessage(FromConfigVar, ToConfigVar)
        email.Subject = DDL_Selection.SelectedValue & " Table"
        email.IsBodyHtml = True

        Select Case DDL_Selection
            Case "Table1"
                Try
                    htmlWriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Table)
                    Table1.RenderControl(htmlWriter)
                    htmlWriter.RenderEndTag()
                    htmlWriter.Flush()

                    result = stringWriter.ToString()
                Finally
                    htmlWriter.Close()
                    stringWriter.Close()
                End Try
        End Select
        mailMessage.Body = result
    Else
        'Do nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Again, this solution is not working, nor do I think I'm even close to being on the right track. Just thought I'd show what I've tried.

Comment: Would you be able to take a screenshot and send that?

Comment: Of which part? The error or a sample of the table?

Comment: Ah, no, I mean as an answer to the problem, can you take a screenshot (and also submit the form if necessary) and send that to the people on the email list.

Comment: @wazz, the form is submitted by the user. Assume the user has no idea how to use computers because that's as close to the truth as I can get, haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override the Page's [VerifyRenderingInServerForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.verifyrenderinginserverform(v=vs.110).aspx) Method to not perform the validation that is causing the issue you can get around this problem:

```
'This is in the Page's Code Behind.
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm (control As Control)
    'Do Nothing instead of raise exception.
End Sub
```

Comment: How would this look in my code example above? Would there be any code needed in the `Sub`?

Comment: No, this should just suppress that exception you were getting... "saying my Textboxes needed to be inside a form with runat="server" in it".

Comment: I get an error `RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();`

Comment: Haha this solution is getting clunkier.  Check out this link for information on how to resolve that error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228718/registerforeventvalidation-can-only-be-called-during-render

Comment: Okay. So, after adding `<%@ Page ............  EnableEventValidation="false" %>`, it works!! I am sending the entire form as an email. Though, each input is surrounded by brackets for some reason. I'm not sure why, but I made a huge step forward with your help.

Comment: Do you know if/how I could send the HTML in Print view instead of Screen?

Answer (score 1):

I got this version working but did not get any user-input returned.
This puts the html into an email; uses HtmlAgilityPack.

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
etc.

protected void btnTableToEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        using(HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            writer.AddAttribute("runat", "server");
            writer.RenderBeginTag("form");

            writer.Write(GetTableHTML());

            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }

        SendEmail(sw);
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private string GetTableHTML()
{
    // uses HtmlAgilityPack.

    var html = new HtmlDocument();
    html.Load(Server.MapPath("~/yourpage.aspx")); // load a file
    var root = html.DocumentNode;

    var table = root.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("id", "").Equals("Table1")).Single();
    return table.InnerHtml;
}

private void SendEmail(StringWriter sw)
{
    // your email routine.
    // ...
    msg.Body = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I want to try to be as vanilla as possible in this code. So, using a third party parser (although seemingly a great parser) is not an ideal solution to this problem.

Comment: Could you write this out in VB? Even if I don't use it, I'd like to try it out. I'm currently having an issue with the line

`var table = root.Descendants().Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("id", "").Equals("Table1").Single();`

In my code (VB) it looks like...

`Dim table = root.Descendants().Where...`

and I'm getting errors using the `Where` function.

Comment: I've never used VB (only VBA) so not sure. I know there's a site or two online that can convert between the two. Not sure why that one line wouldn't work. Only guess is a missing using statement (Linq?).