# How to print a report from an SQL database using Visual Basic?

Tags: sql, vba, printing

I have an SQL database with records of different library members. At the end of the month, I need to print out a sheet with all members who haven't returned their library books and their addresses. I am okay with the query, but I don't know how to print out the results on a paper in tabular form? Is there a proper way of doing this?

I was thinking of writing the results to an html document and printing that. Would that be a good idea? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya hope link below help; :

[links] - with code

1) Export to excel - [export from sql server to excel file using asp.net and vb.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621577/export-from-sql-server-to-excel-file-using-asp-net-and-vb-net)

2) Crystal report - http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/crystal_report_from_sql_query_string.htm

hope its helps, if you want you can share what you have done, I can try and fix your code. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Crystal Reports, an extension that shipped with VB6: http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/using-crystal-reports-vb6-tutorial

Or a very crude way would be to create an MS Excel file rather than an HTML file as it would give you much more structure control along with an excellent editor post generation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Word mailmerge with ODBC databases to create directories ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294693 ). A HTML document also sounds quite useful.