# Convert xlsx to XML spreadsheet 2003 in ASP.net c# programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, excel

I have a web application that reads from XML, but the users need to upload .xlsx or .xls files.

How do I programatically convert the Excel files into XML spreadsheet 2003?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at a [similar question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039451/alternative-to-office-interop-for-document-generation). The following alternatives are mentioned (among others):

- [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) which is free and open source
- [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/.net), in your case [Apose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx), although it is definitely not free

I have no experience with either of these.

Using Microsoft Office Interop assemblies is **[not an option](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757)** - it just won't work:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Answer (score -3):

You can read an existing excel file and save it into required format: `xlXMLSpreadsheet`.

Below is the sample code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open("D:\\sample.xlsx");
wb.SaveAs("D:\\sample.xml", FileFormat: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet);
wb.Close();
app.Quit();
```

Comment: -1 Using Office interop assemblies on a web server is a really bad idea. See http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757