# Interop Excel not closing process

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, excel, office-interop

I have been struggling with this problem for a couple of days, I have made reasearch and applied all the suggestions I found on various forums but I'm still unable to solve it.

My problem is with excel using interop library, I have an excel file used as template, so I am  opening it and saving in a new location with a new name. Everything works great except that the Excel process keeps runing after the file is created and closed.

This is my code

```
protected string CreateExcel(string strProjectID, string strFileMapPath)
{
    string strCurrentDir = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Templates/");
    string strFile = "Not_Created";

    Application oXL;
    Workbook oWB;        

    oXL = new Application();
    oXL.Visible = false;

    Workbooks wbks = oXL.Workbooks;
    //opening template file
    oWB = wbks.Open(strFileMapPath);        

    oXL.Visible = false;
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    strFile = strProjectID + "_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".xlsx";
    //Saving file with new name
   oWB.SaveAs(strCurrentDir + strFile, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, null, null,    false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, false, false, null, null);

    oWB.Close(false, strCurrentDir + strFile, Type.Missing);

    wbks.Close();

    oXL.Quit();


    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbks);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);


    oWB = null;
    oXL = null;
    wbks = null;
    GC.Collect();

    return strFile;
}
```

As you can see I am closing and releasing all the objects but the application does not quit.

I'm testing in a Windows Server 2008(production) and Windows 7(development) both in 32bits with IIS7.

Comment: You cannot use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/158706/16391

Comment: @JohnSaunders: You *can*, it is just a very, very bad idea ;-)

Comment: @StingyJack: no, that one is not due to asp.net.

Comment: @roma8716: As John points out, it is not a good idea (at all) to use interop from ASP.Net.  I would suggest that you either use a component that is suited to this task (e.g. http://epplus.codeplex.com/), or write a windows service that accepts queued requests to process the Excel files.

Comment: @JohnSaunders. From a .NET perspective, you cannot tell that one or the other is ASP.NET.

Comment: I would use a open source lib like the one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c-sharp

Comment: There is also https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Comment: @StingyJack: Not true. A desktop application will be running a message pump, and will be in use by a single user at a time, and likely all on the UI thread (which will not be present in ASP.NET). You can try this, but suicide is easier and safer.

Comment: There are no clues in the item I mentioned that indicate the host type.

Comment: @StingyJack: I see your point now. However, from experience, I'm pretty sure that the problem he's seeing is related to using Office Interop in ASP.NET. See also "[Office Interop with 64bit Windows in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031513/office-interop-with-64bit-windows-in-asp-net)" where, big hint, the problem wasn't 64 bits.

Comment: Oh yeah, I avoid Office Interop if I can. Its historically been a painful experience regardless of host.

Comment: @Eric J.:I tried out epplus an everithing was working ok until I needed to insert a new row. The InsertRow method is inserting the row but it is also adding a column to all the following rows of the inserted row. So I'm testing Spreadsheetgera right now  and it is working ok but I'd prefer a free option.

Comment: @StingyJack I checked the excellibrary but it only works with .xsl and I need support for .xslx files.

Comment: Check the result from System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject, if it is not 0, something else is holding the COM reference. Try FinalReleaseComObject.

Comment: Try using the GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); after GC.Collect()

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
Process excelProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")[0];
if (!excelProcess.CloseMainWindow())
{
 excelProcess.Kill();
}
```

Comment: Translated into VB.Net  Dim excelProcess(0) As Process
        excelProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")

Comment: This is not good for ASP.NET (server) scenario. You are going to kill the instances which appeared after you began handling your request and which are currently handling other requests.

Comment: this should work but if you/(your customer) have another excel worksheet opened that can close it instead of this app

Answer (score 3):

This is how I got around this problem:

```
// Store the Excel processes before opening.
Process[] processesBefore = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");

// Open the file in Excel.
Application excelApplication = new Application();
Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(Filename);

// Get Excel processes after opening the file.
Process[] processesAfter = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");

// Now find the process id that was created, and store it.
int processID = 0;
foreach (Process process in processesAfter)
{
    if (!processesBefore.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(process.Id))
    {
        processID = process.Id;
    }
}

// Do the Excel stuff

// Now close the file with the COM object.
excelWorkbook.Close();
excelApplication.Workbooks.Close();
excelApplication.Quit();

// And now kill the process.
if (processID != 0)
{
    Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
    process.Kill();
}
```

Comment: This is nicest as it checks for existing instances first.

Comment: This is not good for ASP.NET (server) scenario. You are going to kill the instances which appeared after you began handling your request and which are currently handling other requests.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here: [How can I get the ProcessID (PID) for a hidden Excel Application instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636319/how-can-i-get-the-processid-pid-for-a-hidden-excel-application-instance)

You can track down your ProcessID via `GetWindowThreadProcessId` API and than kill the process that particularly matches your instance of Excel Application object.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(int hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

Process GetExcelProcess(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp)
{
     int id;
     GetWindowThreadProcessId(excelApp.Hwnd, out id);
     return Process.GetProcessById(id);
}

void TerminateExcelProcess(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp)
{
     var process = GetExcelProcess(excelApp);
     if (process != null)
     {
          process.Kill();
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to import dll. Is there any other way to do the trick.

Comment: @UmerFarooq You can iterate through all the `Process` instances and check the `Process.MainWindowHandle` against the `excelApp.Hwnd`. All `Process` instances are available through the `Process.GetProcesses`

Answer (score 1):

I created this method for it, in my tests it works.

```
private void ClearMemory(Application excelApp) {
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    excelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0);
    excelApp.Quit();
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) to create excel document instead of using interop assemblies. It runs a lot faster in my experience and it's easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the VB version  -- I have a large project that uses this and not the time to convert to a better system, so here is the same answer... in vb.NET

Use this to get the process ID (Prior to opening the excel sheet)

```
Dim excelProcess(0) As Process
excelProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel")
```

After you're done with your sheet:

```
xlWorkBook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
xlApp.Workbooks.Close()
xlApp.Quit()
'Kill the process
If Not excelProcess(0).CloseMainWindow() Then
    excelProcess(0).Kill()
End If
```

Comment: This is not good for ASP.NET (server) scenario. You are going to kill the instances which appeared after you began handling your request and which are currently handling other requests.

Comment: Thanks @ZverevEugene - Do you point me in the direction of a better way to code this?

Comment: Actually, yes. Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636319/how-can-i-get-the-processid-pid-for-a-hidden-excel-application-instance

Answer (score 0):

Simple rule: **avoid** using double-dot-calling expressions, such as this:

```
var workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(/*params*/)
```

([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17367570/6629562))

Answer (score -2):

```
oWB.Close(false, strCurrentDir + strFile, Type.Missing);
oWB.Dispose();
wbks.Close();
wbks.Dispose();
oXL.Quit();
oXL.Dispose();


System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbks);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
```

Comment: As stated in the question comments above. This is not advised from ASP.NET.